# react-native-image-crop-picker build issue for android

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, react-native-image-crop-picker

I'm trying to install `react-native-image-crop-picker` for my react-native app. For IOS it build without an issue. Android built fails with this issue.

```
> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
375 actionable tasks: 355 executed, 20 up-to-date
...
/Users/*project_directory*/node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/android/src/main/java/com/reactnative/ivpusic/imagepicker/PickerModule.java:406: error: cannot find symbol
        permissionsCheck(activity, promise, Collections.singletonList(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU ? Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE : Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES), new Callable<Void>() {
                                                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable TIRAMISU
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/Users/*project_directory*/node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/android/src/main/java/com/reactnative/ivpusic/imagepicker/PickerModule.java:406: error: cannot find symbol
        permissionsCheck(activity, promise, Collections.singletonList(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU ? Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE : Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES), new Callable<Void>() {
```

My built tool versions are here.
`"react-native": "0.69.9",`
`"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.39.0"`

```
buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 31
```

According to this [issue](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1892) in github, there is a suggestion to change `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` to 33. Changing sdk versions to 33 worked for me also. But in my case, I need to hold the sdk version 31. Is there is a way to fix this issue without changing the sdk version?

Comment: upgrading from 31.0.0 to 33.0.0 would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducing the version from "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.39.0" to "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.38.1" worked for me